# Upload UWP app to Microsoft Store in all 3 platforms (x86, x64, ARM)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a 3rd party DLL (in all 3 platforms x86, x64 and ARM) referring in my UWP app. Due to this reason I have to change my reference manually each time I need to build my UWP app to specific platforms.

Now I need to publish the app to the store but I can't select all platforms due to the manual handling of the 3rd party DLL. I tried building the app in release mode separately and tried to upload to the store but it does not allow. Only way possible is by selecting all 3 platforms in the crate app package window.

Please help me to find a way to upload the app supporting all 3 platforms. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I can't use any-cpu option since the dll and the app both refers to SQLite libraries which do not support any-cpu.

[image]

Comment: Create an [app bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) that contains three separate app packages for the x86, x64, and ARM configurations? What's the issue with using the wizard?

Comment: Store is not accepting 3 packages. If you can build all 3 at once you can see only one appxupload file generates. That’s only the store accepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a prebuild event to change which DLL to import before each build.

`copy "$(ProjectDir)\Extensions\$(PlatformName)\IronOne.Converter.Windows.dll" "$(ProjectDir)"\Extensions\Active"`

From there you can just change your `DllImport` to `$(ProjectDir)"\Extensions\Active`

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. Adding this prebuild command sort my problems out. Now I can successfully submit the package supporting all platforms to the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at this tool by which you may create a package manually and it also offers lots of advanced options.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool

Comment: I don’t think this is what I want. This tool does not create appxupload file. Which is required for store upload.

Comment: Ah I see.. sorry I don't have time right now to take a deeper look.. sumimasen :(

Comment: @SurenSaluka This is how to create the appx.upload manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-your-app-package-upload-file-manually